# Creating a trigger with validation from table

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have 2 tables :table1 and table2 and table2 has column phone which is varying character. I want to execute this :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER table1_trigger
  AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN ( table2.phone <> 'something' )
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE myprocedure();
```

but I get error on   WHEN ( table2.name <> 'something' ) and I am using postgresql

The idea is if there is a column name in table2 with value  'something' then create the trigger and execute the procedure

Answer (score 0):

you cannot reference attributes from a different table in the when condition. The condition can only be on OLD or NEW values. See here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html for more information on how to create a trigger

Comment: Thanks for the information,but any suggestion how can I do it ?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Your condition doesn't make sense. The trigger is executed when a row in table1 is updated. This row doesn't have a connection to table2. And even if it did, e.g. via a foreign key, you'd have to implement that logic in your procedure.

Comment: I want the procedure to be executed when a column in table2 is equal to 'something'l

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, but if you really want to do it, add a check for this condition in the beginning of the procedure. If the condition is not true, then don't execute the rest of the procedure, if it is, then do.

Comment: BEGIN
        IF  table2.phone <> ''sth' THEN
            CREATE TRIGGER table1_trigger
          AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

           EXECUTE PROCEDURE myprocedure();
            END IF;
            END        //I guess that will work?